# Convert a list of Pandas Dataframes to a single list?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a list of 10 data frames (each data frame with a different number of rows and columns) :

```
list1 = [df1, df2, df3,....df10]
```

Converting each data frame individually gives me a list of lists:

```
list1[i].values.tolist()
```

like so

```
[[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]]
```

Is there an elegant way to convert all the data frames in 'list1' to a single list like below?

```
[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]
```

Comment: merge the list1 with `pd.concat`, and use `df.values.flatten()`

Comment: @Ferris does this work if each data frame has a different number of rows and columns?

Comment: or you can handle each df then merge the list by `+`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `flatten()` to flatten the values.

```
list1 = [df1, df2, df3,....df10]

result = list()
for df in list1:
    result += df.values.flatten().tolist()
```